# help with foreach loop

Tags: php

Want to get rid of the depth -- 1 field and only display the name and its value.

Functions file

```
    <?php 
    public function getLocalSubNodes($node_name){
    $stmt = conn::getInstance()->prepare(" SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth FROM categories AS node, categories AS parent, categories AS sub_parent,
            (
            SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
            FROM categories AS node,
            categories AS parent
            WHERE node.left_node BETWEEN parent.left_node AND parent.right_node
            AND node.name = :node_name
            GROUP BY node.name
            ORDER BY node.left_node
            )AS sub_tree
    WHERE node.left_node BETWEEN parent.left_node AND parent.right_node
    AND node.left_node BETWEEN sub_parent.left_node AND sub_parent.right_node
    AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
    GROUP BY node.name
    HAVING depth <= 1
    ORDER BY node.left_node");
    $stmt->bindParam(':node_name', $node_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    ?>


I instantiate the class calling the getLocalSubNodes functions

    <?php 

    $hierachy = new hierachy;
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new recursiveArrayIterator($hierachy->getLocalSubNodes($name1)));
    try {
        foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
            {
            echo  $key.' -- '.$value.'<br />';
            }
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        } ?>
```

resulting in

> > name -- mp3 players
> >
> > depth -- 1
> >
> > name -- cd players
> >
> > depth -- 1
> >
> > name -- 2 way radios
> >
> > depth -- 1

I only want the

> name -- mp3 players
>
> name -- cd players
>
> name -- 2 way radios

want to get rid of the depth.

in the database I don't have such a field called depth it seems to be generated in the query above, I need the query to calculate the depth but I don't want to print the depth and its value, Don't need the depth and its value to be printed or echo.

so I considered it could be the for each loop.

not sure if that's the issue here though.

thanks.

Comment: **PLEASE** format your code properly. This isn't a forum, so `[code]` tags do absolutely nothing. Click the little `code` and `quote` buttons, please.

Comment: Please properly indent and mark you code, its totally unreadable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are selecting it in your query here:

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
```

So, in your foreach you would either need to check for the key you want, or check for the keys you do not want.

```
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
    {
    if ($key != 'name') {
       continue;
    }
    echo  $key.' -- '.$value.'<br />';
    }
```

Being an example of the latter.

If you want everything **but** depth, then do this:

```
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
    {
    if ($key == 'depth') {
       continue;
    }
    echo  $key.' -- '.$value.'<br />';
    }
```

Comment: Who told you that? Look at the third one down: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php edit: And evidently Mr. Ferraro has removed his comment, making this one look confusing.

Comment: it is depth which i don't want to display, I still want the query to do its job but not to display the depth in there. I will test it

Comment: @Cthos: Yes, you were correct with your !=, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: So far ferrero little condition got rid of the $key and $value of the field depth.

Comment: @fello2: Yeah, his is essentially the same as the second option I gave, aside from I use a `continue;` to skip to the next iteration of the loop, simply because I think it looks a bit cleaner. Computationally they should be about the same in terms of processing speed as well. So it's up to your preference. I'm also biased against not using braces in if statements.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to add an if statement in your display

```
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
{
    if ($key <> "depth")
        echo  $key.' -- '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: So <> means not depth, that will be a great release man, that little sucker depth been taking two days of my life, I have been trying to fix that one for a while thanks Tyler

Comment: <> and != both mean 'does not equals'. I'm not sure where this guy got his info on != not existing, but if you want a reference to all the operators, here you go: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks Ferrero you did a great job on the conditions, it not only got rid of the $key value of the depth field but it also got rid of the value in this case 1

Comment: Don't forget to click the Green Check mark next to any answer that solved this problem for you so other users know which solution works.